# Magento2 simple store switcher for UI grid

Tags: magento2, multistore, grid, uicomponent

Is it possible to add simple store switcher for magento2 UI grid like in magento1:
[image]

(Store switcher must be located not in "Filters" tab)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the switcher block to the top of the listing in layout (same as reports grid do):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">            
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher" name="adminhtml.report.grid.store_switcher" as="store_switcher">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="use_confirm" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                    <argument name="switch_websites" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                    <argument name="switch_store_groups" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                    <argument name="switch_store_views" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                    <argument name="default_selection_name" xsi:type="string" translate="true">All Websites</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="your_grid_listing_component"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```